Docker not running on windows
I have been struggling to install Docker Desktop for a while now.
I'm not the admin on my computer but my user has been added to the docker user group.
When I try to run docker this is what I get:
docker run hello-world


docker: error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Head "http:////./pipe/docker_engine/_ping": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
See 'docker run --help'

I've looked up this issue and saw that it might be that docker daemon is not running and so when I execute:
docker version

I get:

error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Get "http:////./pipe/docker_engine/v1.45/version": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
Client:
Cloud integration: v1.0.35+desktop.13
Version: 26.1.1
API version: 1.45
Go version: go1.21.9
Git commit: 4cf5afa
Built: Tue Apr 30 11:48:43 2024
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Context: default

I don't actually know if this is an issue with daemon since the error is a bit different than on the following thread: Docker cannot start on Windows
(the error in that case is not the same when running docker version)
I just ran the command like it said on the thread linked above (in the administrator shell):
& 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon

and i get:

switching to windows engine: request failed and retry attempts exhausted: Post "http://ipc/engine/switch": open \.\pipe\dockerBackendApiServer: The system cannot find the file specified.


Is the client installed properly? i remember to had some issues because my WSL 2 was setup correctly.

@Dwza would you know how i could check that?

Beseids reinstalling it? No :) I would just set it up new and clean just to make sure everything is set up correct. https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/

@Dwza unfortunately it's like the 3rd time I install it lol ://

@LouiseBardouil If you found a solution by yourself, please post it as an answer to your question, so others can see it is taken care of.

my issue was kinda stupid, I just didnt add correctly my user to the group - if on a company computer this could be userful:
execute the following command in the administartor power shell:
net localgroup docker-users "COMPANY DOMAIN\your-user-id" /ADD

You can find the domain like this:
Press Windows + R to open the Run dialog box.
Type msinfo32 and press Enter.
In the System Information window, look for "Domain" in the right pane under "System Summary". Or look at User and it should give you COMPANY DOMAIN\your-user-id

The specified local group does not exist....
